# Is the AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT with Navi 10 compatible with Blender 2.81 on Linux?

Tags: gpu

If I want to select my GPU under OpenCL, I only get the following message:
`"No compatible path tracking GPUs found. Cycles are rendered on the CPU"`

I've already tried to find the reason (Google, etc.), but I can not find a reason or a solution.
I think my GPU actually should be supported! (or am I wrong here?)
I've enclosed my system information below this post.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Thanks,

Oliver

---

**System information**
**System:**
Host: terra
Kernel: 5.4.0-2.gf582eb1 standard x86_64
bits: 64
Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.17.3
Distribution: openSUSE Tumbleweed 20191127

**Machine:**
Type: Desktop
Mobo: ASUSTeK
Model: Pro WS X570-ACE (v: Version X.0x)
Serial Number: `<root required>`
UEFI: American Megatrends (v: 1104, date: 10/29/2019)

**CPU:**
Topology: 8-Core
Model: AMD Ryzen 7 3800X
Bits: 64
Type: MT MCP
L2 Cache: 4096 KiB
Speed: 4123 MHz
min / max: 2200/4000 MHz
core speed (MHz):
1: 4119, 2: 4120, 3: 4120, 4: 4140,
5: 4139, 6: 4113, 7: 4108, 8: 4102,
9: 4108, 10: 4120, 11: 4135, 12: 4149,
13: 4143, 14: 4140, 15: 4121, 16: 4102

**Graphics:**
Device 1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD / ATI] Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5700/5700 XT]
Driver: amdgpu
v: Kernel

Display: x11
Server: X.org 1.20.6
Driver: amdgpu
FAILED: ati
unload: fbdev, modesetting, radeon, vesa
Resolution: `<xdpyinfo missing>`

**OpenGL:**
Renderer: AMD NAVI10 (DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-2.gf582eb1 standard LLVM 9.0.0)
v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.6

**Info:**
Processes: 356
Operating time: 1h 49m
Memory: 62.72 GiB
used: 1.80 GiB (2.9%)
Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.36

Comment: Harware questions are off-topic for this site, but you should it is quite obvious it's a driver issue. Driver: amdgpu FAILED

Comment: due to lack of formatting it may look like that, though it actually is a separate line and only the ati portion has failed.

Comment: You need to use the proprietary drivers from AMD, not the ones supplied by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need OpenCL capable Drivers. Install theese ontop of amdgpu.

https://www.amd.com/de/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-navi-linux